# Creating default object from empty value

Tags: theming

I am having issues with a template - in the template.php there is code causing a warning:

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in theme545_preprocess_html() (line 31 of /home/noramtow/public_html/sites/all/themes/theme545/template.php).

The line in questions is this:

```
$vars['rdf']->version = 'version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"';
```

The whole section of code looks like this:

```
function theme545_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
if (module_exists('rdf')) {
$vars['doctype'] = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML+RDFa 1.1//EN">' . "\n";
$vars['rdf']->version = 'version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"';
$vars['rdf']->namespaces = $vars['rdf_namespaces'];
$vars['rdf']->profile = ' profile="' . $vars['grddl_profile'] . '"';
} else {
$vars['doctype'] = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . "\n";
$vars['rdf']->version = '';
$vars['rdf']->namespaces = '';
$vars['rdf']->profile = '';
}
$vars['classes_array'][] = 'body';
```

I'm not great with PHP - anyone have any idea how to fix this or what's causing it??
Thanks for any help you can give!!
Candace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your system wants to make sure $vars['rdf'] is a valid object before assigning properties to it.

Try adding:

```
if (empty($variables['rdf']) || !is_object($variables['rdf'])) {
  $vars['rdf'] = new stdClass();
}
```

Just above your line 31.

For safety's sake, add it above

```
if (module_exists('rdf')) {
```

That way the object will get initialized regardless of whether the RDF module is enabled or not.

Comment: I added it an uploaded, but it's still showing the same warning.  :-(

Comment: Rats. Do you know what version of PHP you have?

Comment: No, but they're a really good hosting company, and they're usually really updated.

Comment: Keeping PHP at the latest version would be risky for a host - they might break Drupal and Wordpress. So you are on Drupal 7 you are using PHP 5.2 or 5.3 - I was able to replicate this error on 5.3 but not 5.2. 

I updated my code with the solution that works for me.

Comment: Has anyone told you that you are BRILLIANT??!!  THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: You are nice. I would feel more brilliant if I got it right on the first try.